# Basic compile issue with QT4

Tags: qt, qt4, g++, mingw32

I've been trying to get a dead simple listing from a university textbook to compile with the newest QT SDK for Windows I downloaded last night. After struggling through the regular nonsense (no make.bat, need to manually add environment variables and so on) I am finally at the point where I can build. But only one of the two libraries seem to work.

The .pro file I use is dead simple:

```
SUBDIRS += utils \
           dataobjects

TEMPLATE = subdirs
```

In each of these two subfolders I have the source for a library. Running QMAKE generates a makefile and running Make runs through all the preliminaries and then fails on the g++ call:

```
g++ -enable-stdcall-fixup -Wl,-enable-auto-import -Wl,-enable-runtime-pseudo-reloc --out-implib,libdataobjects.a -shared -mthreads -Wl -Wl,--out-implib,c:\Users\Cobus\workspace\lib\libdataobjects.a -o ..\..\lib\dataobjects.dll object_script.dataobjects.Debug  -L"c:\Users\Cobus\Portab~1\Qt\2010.02.1\qt\lib" -LC:\Users\Cobus\workspace\lib -lutils -lQtXmld4 -lQtGuid4 -lQtCored4
c:/users/cobus/portab~1/qt/2010.02.1/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lutils
```

The problem seems to be right near the end of the command line, where -lutils is added, indicating that there is a library by the name of utils. While I would have expected to see that, you'll notice the library names after --out include lib in the name, so they become libutils and libdataobjects. I have tried to figure out why this is happening, to no avail.

Anyone have an idea what's going on?

Comment: In GCC it is standard to use -lname for libname and omit the "lib" part

Comment: If you generated the Makefile automatically, what happens if you just remove the -lutils part? (by editing the makefile)

Comment: Your .pro file is just says that there are two subdirectories utils and dataobjects each of them contain its own .pro file with the information about how to build its content. You should also provide those .pro files to get meaningfully answer on your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `.pro` file uses the `SUBDIRS` template which requires a .pro file matching the directory name for each subdir.  You should have a `utils\utils.pro` and `dataobjects\dataobject.pro` file as well.

Is `c:\Users\Cobus\workspace\lib\libdataobjects.a` built correctly?  If not, check the sub directory `.pro` files.

With what you posted, I would not expect anything to compile.  You need targets in the sub-directory `.pro` files to build anything.

Answer (score 0):

Their seems to be another pro file as the generated Makefile is pulling QtXml which it wont do by default.

Please check the subdirs for any .pro or .pri files .. one of them will have answer to your confusion